# Lazy initialization of a C++ singleton in declaration or in implementation

Tags: c++, design-patterns, singleton

I know that the singleton pattern is usually considered a bad design and hence discouraged, but this question concerns the implementation aspects, not the appropriateness of the singleton pattern.

Consider the following three implementations of a singleton in C++ using lazy initialization:

**1: Using pointer, split between declaration and implementation**

Singleton.hpp:

```
class Singleton {
public:
   static Singleton* instance();
private:
   Singleton() {}
   static Singleton* singleton;
};
```

Singleton.cpp:

```
Singleton* Singleton::singleton = nullptr;

Singleton* Singleton::instance() {
    if( nullptr == singleton ) {
        singleton = new Singleton();
    }
    return singleton;
}
```

**2: Using reference, split between declaration and implementation**

Singleton.hpp:

```
class Singleton {
public:
   static Singleton& instance();
private:
   Singleton() {}
};
```

Singleton.cpp:

```
Singleton& Singleton::instance() {
    static Singleton singleton;
    return singleton;
}
```

**3: Using reference, inline in declaration**

Singleton.hpp:

```
class Singleton {
public:
    static Singleton& instance() {
         static Singleton singleton;
         return singleton;
    }
private:
    Singleton() {}
}
```

I personally like and use the third version. But is there any good reason to prefer the first or the second version instead?

It is my understanding that in the third version there is an instance of the object for each translation unit that includes `Singleton.hpp` and then the linker picks a single one. Does this causes any side effect?

And are there any side effects using the third one in a shared library?

Bonus questions: which implementation is actually the "Meyer's singleton"?

Comment: Well references cannot be null, so the second and third methods cannot be used for lazy instantiation

Comment: @spug Local static variables with initialization will be initialized the first time the function is called.

Comment: The second option (Meyers Singleton) is guaranteed to be thread safe in C++11, just so you know.

Comment: @StoryTeller The second version should also be thread safe. The only difference between them is that the in the second alternative the `instance` function can't be inlined. The initialization of the instance is still thread-safe.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude "The second option" and also "The second version" ...? is this a typo or which one do you mean?

Comment: @tobi303 - It means I got confused, and ninja corrected it before Some dude hit submit.

Comment: In all the 3 cases you have no explicit control over singleton creation. I do realize that this question is about "lazy" initialization, but I consider such initialization not acceptable. And in cases 2 and 3 you have no explicit control over singleton destruction as well. Also singleton access method should return a reference even if there is a pointer stored internally.

Comment: @VTT - *"No explicit control"*, well that's the point of lazy evaluation...

Comment: @StoryTeller Yes, but I just suggest to implement delayed (or may be optional) initialization rather than lazy so control over singleton lifetime is not lost.

Comment: @VTT - All references I could find use "delayed initialization" and "lazy initialization" as synonyms. I'm not quite sure what you mean by a better solution.

Comment: @StoryTeller The difference in these approaches is that during lazy initialization we allow singleton to be created at the first use whenever it happens while during delayed initialization singleton must be explicitly created by singleton owner entity prior to first use and any attempt to access it while it is not yet initialized leads to call to `abort()` or at least to debug assertion.

Answer (score 4):

The first one is **not** thread safe.

```
 if( nullptr == singleton ) {
    singleton = new Singleton();
}
```

It could happen that multiple threads could execute the allocation statement and create a *memory leak*.

The second and the third ones are thread-safe *since C++11*, because:

> If multiple threads attempt to initialize the same static local
>   variable concurrently, the initialization occurs exactly once (similar
>   behavior can be obtained for arbitrary functions with std::call_once).

from [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration).

I'd prefer the third one because the inline optimisations are more likely.

Comment: It is correct to define that an "undefined behavior"? To me that is just a plain thread unsafe code.

Comment: @Wizard79 You're probably right, I've edited the answer.