# a value of type "Tree (*)[H]" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "Tree **"

Tags: c++, arrays

So basically i have `getOrGenForest()` function and I need for it to generate a 2D array only once and the rest of times when it's called just to return `Forest` but looks like I did something wrong and can't figure out what. Any help?

```
Tree** Planet::getOrGenForest()
{
    if(Forest != NULL){
      return Forest;
    }
    Tree newForest[W][H];
    for (int i=0; i<H; i++)
    {
        for (int j=0; j<W; j++)
        {
           newForest[i][j]={rand()% 4 + 0};
        }
    }
    Forest = newForest;
    return Forest;
}
```

I did tried to do it with other ways, but basically i just need to generate an array one time to use for stuff in other class.

Comment: We need a [mcve]

Comment: Do you want to [lazy initialize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45053688/lazy-initialization-of-a-c-singleton-in-declaration-or-in-implementation) your forest?

Comment: In C++ 2D arrays and double pointers are not the same thing (and not compatible with each other). You need to decide which you want and stick with it.

Comment: Two things: An array of arrays is not the same thing as a pointer to a pointer (see e.g. [this old answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18440205/casting-void-to-2d-array-of-int-c/18440456#18440456) for "drawing" of the difference); And you try to return a pointer to a local variable, whose life-time will end immediately when the function return, so the pointer you return will become immediately invalid.

Comment: The simple solution to both problems is to use `std::array` instead. Optionally use `std::vector`.

Comment: You are also attempting to assign the address of a local array to a pointer. That will not work either because the array is destroyed at the end of the `getOrGenForest` function.

Comment: Well, i think for my case 2d array is better way to do it for what i want

Comment: Well then you need to change `Tree**` to `Tree (*)[W]`. I am assuming that `W` is a constant. You also need to use dynamic allocation to allocate your array.

Comment: On a totally different note, why do you add zero in `rand()% 4 + 0`? Adding zero to any integer will do nothing. And C++ have had [much better PRNG functionality](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) for a long time now.

Comment: i want for value in an array to have 4 different value so i can basically divide them into types

Comment: If `W` and `H` are not constants then you cannot use an array, you must use pointers. In C++ array bounds must be constants. But better than pointers would be `std::vector`. Then you could declare the vector in your class and just **resize** it in your function. Much simpler code.

Comment: `W` and `H` here are constants that are pretty much entered by user

Comment: @NotSenpai If they are entered by the user they are not constants.

Comment: Yes, `rand() % 4` will give you that, a number between `0` and `3` (inclusive). So why add zero?

Comment: Seems like the simple solution is `std::vector<std::vector<Tree>> Forest;` in your class. That will create a zero sized 2D vector, then you can resize that vector to `W` and `H` in your function, once only.

Comment: Array dimensions need to be *compile-time* constants. Any value entered by a user at run-time are not compile-time constant. That means you can't use C-style array, nor `std::array`. You *must* use `std::vector`. Or use pointers and explicit memory allocations, which brings in a heap of trouble. Just use `std::vector`.

Comment: So my solution is to use vector instead of array for this?

Comment: I think so. Really you rarely use arrays in C++ code, std::vector (or std::array) are just so much better.

Comment: Looks like my uni needs an update on their books then. Time to learn vectors to implement feature that i want to be there and is not neccesary at all